# Can't run a Flask app on Ubuntu 16.04 VM

Tags: ubuntu, flask, web-deployment, wsgi, gunicorn

I have a Flask app, that i am trying to deploy on Azure, using Ubuntu 16.04 VM.

I am using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) guide.

I am able to run it with no errors: 
[image: flask running]

However, when I am trying to reach http://[ip address]:5000 in the browser, I get "This site can not be reached".

What are the usual causes when this happen?

Answer (score 0):

1. check if you can reach it on vps
2. check your nginx config